# See what routes an instantiated Backbone.Router is watching for

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I'm looking for a way to inspect a Backbone.Router and see what routes it's looking for.

If you add routes after instantiation using myroute.route(a,b,c), I can't figure out how to see the full list of routes.

Code example:

```
var myRoute = new Backbone.Router({ 'routes':{ 'home':'goHome' } })
myRoute.route('settings','settings',goSettings)
```

I'd like to be able to inspect 'myRoute' and see both the 'settings' and the 'home' route, but I can't figure out a way. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the list of regex expressions being listend for in `Backbone.history.handlers`, but those are narsty to read. There are They look like this:

```
Backbone.history.handlers[0] -> Object { route=RegExp, callback=function()}
route RegExp /^myModuleTests$/
```

Still looking for a better solution, but I'm afraid this might be all there is.